# QML: SoundEffect not working, Audio does

Tags: qt, audio, symbian, qml

I have two custom QML elements for audio, one for playing music (and extends the QML Audio element) and one for playing sound effects (which extends QML's SoundEffect element).

I am able to play background music with no problem, but when I try to play a sound effect, the interface freezes for a couple of seconds (the music keeps playing) and then when it unfreezes, I get the Windows error sound.

Here is what I have (the music has a similar architecture):

MySoundEffect.qml

```
Loader {
   id: container
   source: "MobilitySoundEffect.qml"

   property bool  valid: item !== null
   property real  audioVolume: 1.0
   property int   loops: 1

   function initialise() {
      if(valid) {
         item.volume = container.audioVolume
         item.loops = container.loops
      }
   }

   function play(filename) { if(valid) item.play(filename); }
   function stop() { if(valid) item.stop(); }
   onLoaded: container.initialise()
   onAudioVolumeChanged: if(valid) item.volume = audioVolume;
}
```

MobilitySoundEffect.qml

```
Item {
   id: container

   property url   source: ""
   property real  volume: 1.0
   property int   loops: 1

   function play(filename) {
      if (settings.isFxOn()) {
         source = filename;
      }
   }

   function stop() { soundEffect.stop(); }
   SoundEffect {
      id: soundEffect
      source: container.source
      volume: container.volume
      loops:  container.loops
      onStatusChanged: if (Audio.Loaded == status) play();
   }
}
```

And here is how I register them (trimmed for brevity):

main.qml

```
Rectangle {
   id: main
   MyAudio {
      id: music
   }
   MySoundEffect {
      id: soundEffects
   }
   PageStack {
      id: pageStack

      Component.onCompleted: {
         pageStack.push(Qt.resolvedUrl("pages/IntroPage.qml"));
      }
   }
}
```

Finally, this is how I call them to play music or a sound effect:

```
soundEffects.play("file://assets/audio/click.ogg");  
music.play("file://assets/audio/menu.mp3");
```

Again, music plays fine, sound effects don't. And, as far as I tested, it has nothing to do with the filetype. I couldn't get wav, mp3 or off to play.

My setup is Windows 7, QtSDK 7.4.7, Symbian 1.1.

Under Microsoft Visual Studio Compiler 9.0 I get the freezing and the error sound, but under MinGW 4.4, there is no freeze or error sound, yet, still no sound effect.

### Update

I have now moved all my assets (qml, audio, txt, etc) into a QResource file and now neither sound effect nor music is playing. Whenever I try to play music I get the following in the output:

> qrc file :/audio/menu.ogg
>   Size 353349
>   Sequential 0

I really need to fix this, so I have started a bounty. Please help.

Thank you in advance.

### Solution (more like a work around)

Indeed, QSound cannot play sounds from a resource and I cannot make the SoundEffect element to work. So my work around is the following:

I use the QML Audio element to play background music (which support fade in/fade out) and I created a SoundEffects class in C++ using Phonon to play the sound effects.

It seems to work fine, so I'm not touching it again.

Comment: Did you write custom QML elements for dealing with audio or are they just wrappers around QtMultimedia ?

Comment: They are just wrappers. Or, to be more precise, A loader has a wrapper which has the audio element. Like in the code examples in my post: MySoundEffect is a load that has MobilitySoundEffect item which wraps Qt's SoundEffect element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the QML Audio element is a wrapper around QSound, which cannot access sound files from Qt Resource File System (Mentioned in the Document)**Note that QSound does not support resources. This might be fixed in a future Qt version.**. Regarding the Windows warning/error sound, I guess, playing the sound effect may be blocking the main UI thread.

It may also be caused, if QSound cannot play two audio files simultaneously. You can try **QtMultimedia or Phonon** if there are some limitations in QSound class.

Comment: I started using Phonon but couldn't make fade in/fade out to work. This is a mobile game, and, as far as I understand, the phonon effects are not available to the mobile.

Comment: I then tried QtMutltimedia, but was completely lost. Then I tried QML Audio, which seemed to have everything. I don't mind about having the sound in a qrc file. That's OK. But I can't get sound effects to work using the QML Sound Effect, which is specifically designed for playing audio simultaneously: doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/qml-soundeffect.html

Comment: I don't see a MyAudio QML Component. Check for errors in there. Try with a simple example to make sure that **QML SoundEffect** can play simultaneously with **QML Audio**, Like with just two buttons. If the problem still persists, update to a Latest Version of Qt Mobility 1.2 or Qt Mobility 1.2.1. and try again. All the best!

Comment: I have omitted the MyAudio because it is similar to the MySoundEffect. It simply uses the Audio element instead of the SoundEffect element. Anyway, I removed entirely the music from my game and tried to only play sound effects. Again, no sound effect whatsoever :(

Comment: Qt Maintenance says that I have QtMobility 1.2.0-1 installed. How can I verify that? I import QtMultimediaKit 1.1 in MobilitySoundEffect.qml. When I try to import 1.2 I get the following error: plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtMultimediaKit": Cannot load library C:/QtSDK/Simulator/Qt/mingw/imports/QtMultimediaKit/declarative_multimediad.dll: The specified module could not be found."

Comment: It may be a bug. Post your bug [here](https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com) with the same example code. I'm sure developers team will contact you about

Comment: AAaaawww.. I was hoping this was not the answer :( I'm gonna try to compile on a Windows XP and see if this is a Windows 7 error. I'll report back. Thanks.

Comment: OK, my work around is the following: I play background music with the Audio element and I use Phonon for sound effects. It seems to work, so I'm not touching it again! Thank you ;)

Comment: Wow! I'm happy that you got a work around :). But if you feel it as a bug, post it to the bug tracker.

Comment: Please note that it now works with Qt 5.7. SoundEffect can directly use a resource file. Please also check the multimedia volume : on my phone, using the volume button does not impact the multimedia volume, but only the ringing volume.

Comment: Good to know that. Using volume button while the music is playing should affect the media volume, rather than the ringtone volume. Also for your information, there is a [volume property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-soundeffect.html#volume-prop).