# Got "Invalid media" trying to play an audio file using "MediaPlayer" in QML

Tags: qt, audio, qml, qt5, media-player

```
MediaPlayer{   //Direct child of the main "ApplicationWindow"
        id:greeterSound
        audioRole: MediaPlayer.SonificationRole
        autoPlay: true
        loops:1
        source: "greeter.mp3"
        muted:false
        volume:1
}
```

This doesn't work for me.No sound.The file `greeter.mp3` has been included in the `.qrc` file and the path is correct.Also I tried using [absolute filesystem path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8522988/11970791).No luck.

The only useful debugging information  I could gather is that the status of that mediaplayer item after loading is [MediaPlayer.InvalidMedia](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html#status-prop):

```
print(greeterSound.status === MediaPlayer.InvalidMedia)
```

returns `qml: true`

I've also tried using other `.mp3` files as the source.Even `.wav` files.But again no luck.Even alternatives like [Audio](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qml-qtmultimedia-audio.html) didn't help.I'm sure my audio files aren't corrupted nor **invalid**.

Comment: the URL you've provided doesn't look either qrc not absolute path.

Comment: @folibis I've tried both ```qrc://``` and absolute path beside that.Also the error isn't ```no such file or directory``` but is **Invalid media**.

Comment: What operating system do you use? I used to get the same errors on Windows, but the same code and the same file worked ok on Linux and Android

Comment: @QtRoS KDE Neon 5.19 unstable(=ubuntu 18.04)